# How to know if another event / user is running on an SPListItem (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: event-handlers, event-receivers, itemupdated

I have a Sharepoint 2010 farm in which is deployed my solution. This solution provides some "data mantain" of some content types. Let me explain:

Suppose I add a file in a document library: when I put it in the folder X, it write on the item that X is his father and has some particular properties.

This works fine, jumping around 4 event:

- Item Adding
- Item Adding
- Item CheckedIn
- Item Updated

Now I'm facing a problem: I have a 3rd party component that permits the move of the document from a document library to another, carrying every metadata of the item.

Suppose Item is in X, so it has Item[Field1] = XField1, Item[Fied2] = Xfield2.

I use this plugin, I move Item to Y. Now Item must have Item[Field1] = YField1, Item[Fied2] = Yfield2.

And now comes the problems, 'cause there are more than one event handler that works on my item:

- Plugin EH wants to put XField1 in Field1
- My EH wants to put YField1 in Field1

The result? It depends on the order:

- Came first Plugin EH?

Does my EH face the problem of the modified Item => Plugin EH wins (not correct)

No facing of the problem => My EH wins (correct)

And viceversa.

I cannot put my hands on Plugin Code so I'm asking: is there any way to know if an Item is being used by someone?

If in my code I can say: "Ok, so Plugin is running on it, I must wait" I'll get the right result.

I tried with Item.File.CheckOutStatus but always figures as NONE

Does anybody have an idea?

I tried also to trap the exception in my code and this works but when my EH cames first the exception occurs on the "black box Plugin side" so I cannot mess with..

Comment: My initial thoughts are only if the file is checked out and checked in by the program?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to determine the [SequenceNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition.sequencenumber.aspx) for the plugin and then give your event receiver a higher value?

Comment: @Kit Menke it depends totally how this 3rd party plugin works. Does the plugin run from an event receiver or workflow? Or is it a separate process that works from the COM on a timer, for example?

Comment: @HughWood Agreed. I was assuming it was also an event receiver since Ziba said "Plugin EH". Probably not a safe assumption> :)

Comment: @Ziba, have you had any movement on this question?

Comment: I solved that in a very ugly way: now my event handler writes down on another list the fact that the file was moves. Another job checkes that list and if is passed a minute from the last modify applies my code..

Comment: When using the Sharepoint Event Receivers, always put your executing code within a lock statement. that way, another thread cannot execute. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What about checking out file before modifying properties? You check if file is available:

- if true, you check out file, do changes and check it back in.
- if file is already checked out you just wait (random amount of time) and then get file status again - after this you have available file or wait again.

There is no need to modify the file, but you can use check in/check out as a lock.